# Openings Recommendations to Study for Unrated Tournament

Tags: opening, tournament, repertoire

In little over a month I am planning on playing an unrated tournament.  Since it is unrated I am assuming the skill level could possibly be from novice to strong.  Due to the entry fee being very low I don't expect masters to be playing. My own play level, for discussion's sake, is amateur.

What openings would be recommended to study in preparation?  I would like to build a repertoire for this event.

Comment: What types of positions do you enjoy? At the amateur level, this is the most important question, really. You most likely won't get to play out the latest theory variations anyways - just try to get into your comfort zone and you should be fine on your own (corresponding to your skill).

Comment: "Amateur" could mean many things. Roughly what rating are we talking about?

Comment: I've VTC'd as being too broad. My challenge back to the OP is: what is wrong with playing the openings you use now? My second challenge is: how much of a benefit could there be to cramming (new) openings prior to a tournament?

Comment: @user1583209 No official rating

Comment: @Bad_Bishop Nothing is wrong currently.  Never stated that there was. This is my second tournament.  First one had to withdraw after only one match played due to unavoible obligations so experience is zilch.  I am not nessecarily looking for 'new' openings.  Never stated that in the OP.  My point was to get opinions and compare to what I already do and prepare so I can have a better opening repertoire.  I want to play more tournaments this year so want better habits.

Comment: @Annatar Open positions I tend to feel more comfortable.  Closed I am slightly more uncomfortable with.

Comment: @Schmoe No inofficial rating (e.g. online rating) either? If you are rated let's say somewhere around 1500 there is not much point investing lots of time into openings. Time would be better spend on tactics training or positional understanding. You can always play openings on general principles at this level. Building an "opening repertoire" within one month including learning all the ideas, avoiding traps, getting practical experience playing the resulting middlegame positions, etc, is **unrealistic**. And even with that repertoire chances are that your typical opponent deviates at move 5....

Comment: @user1583209 I play on various servers that use Glicko, Glicko-2, ELO, ICCF and another I can't find the rating system.  Live chess and correspondance play and various amounts of games .  Ranging from 1600's to 1000's.  Tactics I practice regularly and positional understanding I am currently reading more to have a better understanding so that is ongoing as well.  This specific question is only about openings only.

Comment: @Schmoe: I understand that this question is about openings only. My point is that for players at your level there is not much point studying opening theory. Most likely most of your losses are due to missed tactics, and following a wrong plan in the middlegame, and not due to misplaying an opening.

Comment: @user1583209  I do agree with you.  I have books and other various resources for middlegame improvement that I am trying to use for study to get better as well.  I guess that is why I was just using this as a discussion means for openings only. Future questions will have better information and not be so generalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally stick to learning a few e4 and d4 variations and maybe the English Opening, though I didn't see it much at lower level play. I am also adding some fun, fairly solid variations if you wanted try the more obscure openings

**Ruy Lopez**
1. e4 e5
2. Nf3 Nc6
3. Bb5

A personal favorite of mine, especially the Rio Gambit Accepted line 1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Bb5 Nf6 4.O-O Nxe4, but in general it can create early control of the center and can lead to a strong position with an active bishop or forcing black to double pawns

---

Not my preference, but I used to see a lot of the **Giuoco Piano**

1. e4 e5  2. Nf3 Nc6  3. Bc4 Bc5

and the **Giuoco Pianissimo**

1. e4 e5  2. Nf3 Nc6  3. Bc4 Bc5 4. d3

I wouldn't stress studying this one

---

**Sicilian Defense** 
1. e4 c5

It's rare for me not to see this opening.

*Sicilian Sveshnikov*
1.e4 c5
2.Nf3 Nc6 
3.d4 cxd4 
4.Nxd4 Nf6 
5.Nc3 e5 
6.Ndb5 d6.

It gives a menacing knight position to white, but allows you to prepare your pieces for development and gains a general grasp in the center

*Sicilian Dragon*
1. e4 c5
2. Nf3 d6
3. d4 cxd4
4. Nxd4 Nf6
5. Nc3 g6

Can create very aggressive and constricting pawn marches for white and a fianchettoed bishop and free queen for black. This is very aggressive and loads of fun to play

---

**English Opening**
1. c4

A very flexible and reliable opening if you are well studied into it.

---

**King's Gambit**
  1. e4 e5  2. f4

A sacrificed pawn for quick development. What's not to like

---

A few others you could also look into are the Pirc Defense, Indian-Defenses, Queen's Gambit, Caro-Kann

Comment: I don't think it is practical to study all of these openings to any reasonable depth within one month.

Comment: Thank you TheAutomaton.  Have you seen much of The French and The Philidor in your experience?  I have seen it a fair amount in my online play.

Comment: I don't see many game with french, though stockfish likes to whip it out on me daily. The philidor I have seen, but it's not something that needs to be studied, I can say it is definitely a position where I win the majority as white without much prior knowledge